# Android studio firebase - Access user info using UID

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

for hours I`ve been trying and struggling to get rest of user attributes to get printed based on using the UID of the user. Here is how the "userRegistration" table looks like in my firebase db:

[UserRegistration Table on firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVKHz.png)

Here is a sample code I tried which actually works perfectly when trying to access values from other tables, but does not work when trying to access data from "UserRegistration" table:

```
     public void getRestOfTheUserAttributes(){
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
     String the_uid = user.getUid();

    DatabaseReference additionalUserInfoRef = rootRef.child("UserRegistration");
    Query userQuery = additionalUserInfoRef.orderByChild("user_id").equalTo(the_uid);

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

                String userName = ds.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                String userMail = ds.child("e-mail").getValue(String.class);
                String nameOfUser = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);

           }
           }
```

Again: this code above works perfectly if i try access data from other tables, but not on the "UserRegistration" table!

Also, I have created a very simple method to try get the rest of values but does not work either..

```
public void getUserProfile(){
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String the_id = user.getUid(); //works perfectly
    String name = user.getDisplayName(); // returns null
    String email = user.getEmail();  //works perfectly!




}
```

Could someone plz help me?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iDs are statistically unique. So you don't need to use for loop to iterate from user data. Just provide the user_id in child you can retrieve that user data directly

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String the_uid = user.getUid();
DatabaseReference additionalUserInfoRef = rootRef.child("UserRegistraion").child(the_uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String userName = dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);
            String userMail = dataSnapshot.child("e-mail").getValue(String.class);
            String nameOfUser = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
   DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
     String the_uid = user.getUid();

    DatabaseReference additionalUserInfoRef = rootRef.child("UserRegistraion");
    Query userQuery = additionalUserInfoRef.orderByKey().equalTo(the_uid);

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                String userName = ds.child("username").getValue(String.class);
                String userMail = ds.child("e-mail").getValue(String.class);
                String nameOfUser = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);

           }
           }
```

First add a reference to node `UserRegistraion`, then to retrieve data according the uid, you need to use `orderByKey()` and check if it is equal to the id of the current user. Then you can iterate and retrieve the data

Comment: why `orderby` ? better just provide the child with userid